New CPU BIOS error - fan seems ok (takes some time to spin up)
I've had my desktop machine for a few years now but very recently have started getting a CPU fan error on bios startup (Asus motherboard).
When entering the BIOS the fan is a sometimes a little under 200 rpm (200 being the threshold to trigger the error) but usually spins up to past 200 after a few seconds, so it seems the error is being prematurely triggered with the fan just taking a few extra seconds to get up to speed.
From searching I appreciate there are options that range from increasing the fan speed to just disabling the error but I'm curious as to why this error hasn't appeared before.
For context my machine is a specialist music production machine intended to be as quiet as possible for recording.
Specs below:

Case: CORSAIR CARBIDE SERIESTM 275Q QUIET CASE
Processor: (CPU) Intel® CoreTM i7 Eight Core Processor i7-9700K (3.6GHz) 12MB Cache
Motherboard: ASUS® PRIME Z390-P: ATX, LGA1151, USB 3.1, SATA 6GBs


The most likely cause is that the fan is failing. It should spin up quickly, quickly enough that the warning does not trigger. The fact it is taking longer to spin up indicates the fan is probably failing. It should not be difficult or particularly expensive to replace the fan.

Understood. Thanks.

The most likely issue here is a fan getting old, dirty, or failing in some other way. The fan should spin up quickly enough that by the time the tests run it is operating within normal parameters. Fans being critical to computers, your computer is correct to warn about a fan failure, and you should not disable this warning without accepting you may change a $50 fix into a $1500 fix by doing so.

Inspect the fan for any visible possible causes for this slowed startup.
If you don't find any visible issues, or resolving them doesn't fix the problem, replace the fan.

